# ¿Como obtener el valor de un input hidden con formData?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy realizando un método registrar usando `FormData` para obtener los valores del formulario, y el problema es que tengo un `input="hidden"` pero no obtengo el valor del componente, pero si me trae de todos los demás `input`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="CodUsuario" id="CodUsuario" />
```

Html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalNuevoTicket" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Ticket</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form id="formRegTicket" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            You have some form errors. Please check below.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            Your form validation is successful!
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="CodUsuario" id="CodUsuario" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Nom_usu_reg">Solicitante</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="Nom_usu_reg" id="Nom_usu_reg" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="correo">Correo</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" name="Correo_usu_reg" id="Correo_usu_reg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Telf_usu_reg">Telefono</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" name="Telf_usu_reg" id="Telf_usu_reg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="area">Area</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <p class="form-control-static" id="descArea">
                                    DESARROLLO
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Tit_problema">Problema</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Problema" name="Tit_problema" id="Tit_problema">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Desc_problema">Descripción</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Descripción del Problema" name="Desc_problema" id="Desc_problema"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="imagen" class="col-md-3 control-label">Adjuntar</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="file" name="imagenLoad" id="imagen">
                                <p class="help-block">
                                    jpg|jpeg|png
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Prioridad">Prioridad</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select class="form-control" name="Prioridad" id="Prioridad">
                                    <option value="">-- Seleccione --</option>
                                    <option value="baja">Baja</option>
                                    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                                    <option value="alta">Alta</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn green" id="btnGuardarTicket">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Mi Ajax

```
registrarTicket: function () {

            var form = new FormData($("#formRegTicket")[0]);
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "./Ticket/registrarTicket",
                data: form,
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache:false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        window.location = "./Ticket";
                    }
                }, error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
```

Mi Controller

```
        public JsonResult registrarTicket(Ticket ticket)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase filebase = Request.Files[0];
            WebImage image = new WebImage(filebase.InputStream);
            ticket.Imagen = image.GetBytes();
            ticket.Fecha_Reg = DateTime.Now;
            ticket.Area = "DESARROLLO";
            ticket.Est_ticket = "Registrado";
            ticket.Flag_est = true;

            this._repo.Agregar(ticket);
            this._repo.Guardar();
            return Json(new { data = true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet })
;        }
```

Cuando empiezo a debuggear mi objeto `CodUsuario` no obtiene valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás no le estás asignando un valor al `input` ya que no veo que menciones como le asignas o si le estás asignando un valor

```
<input type="hidden" name="CodUsuario" id="CodUsuario" value="myValue"/>
```

Para asignarle un valor desde js.

```
document.getElementById('CodUsuario').value = 'myValue';

//con querySelector
document.querySelector('#CodUsuario').value = 'myValue';
```